# How find the collation of .NET SQL Client Provider

Tags: .net

How to find the Collation that is used by .NET SqlClient Provider and change the collation in .net SqlClient Provider.

Comment: pls see these 2 questions  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065289/setting-collation-property-in-the-connection-string-to-sql-server-2005 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210189/how-to-set-collation-for-a-connection-in-sql-server

Comment: The .NET SQL Client Provider doesn't have any collation - it's the SQL Server **database** you're connecting/connected to that has such a collation (and the server also has a default collation defined)